# Audit login trigger for permission changes sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

In my office some one changed the permissions of users on production database. so after that i have decided to write a ddl kind of trigger to audit permission changes. I have googled for this but i couldn't find a proper solution. So can you people suggest me few links or any sample code?

I would like to capture who changed the permissions and when permissions got changed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check  [this](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/auditing-security-changes-in-sql-server-2/)
out.

```
CREATE TRIGGER DDL_AUDIT_Logins ON ALL SERVER
FOR DDL_DATABASE_SECURITY_EVENTS AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @EventsTable TABLE (
    EType NVARCHAR(max)
    ,EObject VARCHAR(100)
    ,EDate DATETIME
    ,EUser VARCHAR(100)
    ,ECommand NVARCHAR(max)
    );
DECLARE @EType NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @ESchema NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @Subject VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE @EObject VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @EObjectType VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @EMessage NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @ETSQL NVARCHAR(max);

SELECT @EType = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]',
 'nvarchar(max)')
,@ESchema = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]',
 'nvarchar(max)')
,@EObject = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]',
 'nvarchar(max)')
,@EObjectType = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)[1]',
'nvarchar(max)')
,@DBName = EVENTDATA().value('
(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]',
 'nvarchar(max)')
,@ETSQL = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]', 
'nvarchar(max)');

INSERT INTO @EventsTable
SELECT @EType
    ,@EObject
    ,GETDATE()
    ,SUSER_SNAME()
    ,@ETSQL;

SET @EMessage = 'Login_Event: ' + @EType + CHAR(10) + 'Event Occured at: '
 + Convert(VARCHAR, GETDATE()) + CHAR(10) + 'Changed Login: ' + @EObject + 
CHAR(10) + 'Changed by: ' + SUSER_SNAME() + CHAR(10) + 'Executed T-SQL: ' + 
@ETSQL

SELECT @Subject = 'SQL Server Login changed on ' + @@servername;

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients = 'DDL_Alert@companydomain.com'
    ,@body = @EMessage
    ,@subject = @Subject
    ,@body_format = 'HTML';

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
GO
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thank you  for your answer i need  to add something like changes in databases like adding new database alerting database,dropping database ..
when it got happen  that information i need to store it in table

Comment: Something that was very non-obvious to me was that "GRANT DATABSE" event included any DB permissions changes to users.

Comment: Where can I find the information for these records in the database or how can I generate a report of that?

Comment: If you want you can change the table variable to a real table and SELECT any record which you want to.